# how to filter by value 1|0 when using count_over_time

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am collecting data into Prometheus from the [mysqld_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/mysqld_exporter) and would like to create a Grafana dashboard in where I could represent the service availability in percentage.

By using this query:

```
 count_over_time(mysql_up{instance="10.0.0.5:9104"}[1m])
```

> the output of `mysql_up` is either 1 or 0

I get the sum of all the data points with either a value of `1|0`, in this case, I am scraping every `15s` so I get `4` data points.

Now for example If from the 4 data points, three had a value of `1` and one with the value of 0, that would be 75% of the availability, I would like to plot the `75%` using:

```
(total_datapoints - datapoints_with_value_0) / total_datapoints * 100
(4-1)/4 * 100
```

But now my problem is how could I query Prometheus to obtain only the data points where the value is  `0`

How to filter by value and then apply the time range?

If I try something like:

```
count_over_time(mysql_up{instance="10.0.0.5:9104"} == 0 [1h])
```

or

```
count_over_time(mysql_up{instance="10.0.0.5:9104"} == 0)[1h])
```

I get the error:

```
parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found solution to your question?

Comment: were you able to figure out the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the following query returns exactly what you want (availability in percentage):

```
100*avg_over_time(mysql_up{instance="10.0.0.5:9104"}[1m])
```